# How to refresh the view when StateRealmObject changes

Tags: swiftui, realm

I have a @StateRealmObject displayed on my view.

When the full object changes, the view is updated (as done on Change country button), but when I just change a property of this object, there is no render of the view (Change name button) !!!

I would have expected the Text to be rendered as the country object has been modified.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

(I can manually force the update of the Text with an id and a new state variable, but this is a bad solution as it can become cumbersome with a big view and there should be a more elegant and state of the art solution).

Thanks for advice, here is a full functional code :

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

let realm = try! Realm()

class Country2: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var code = ""
    @Persisted var name = ""

    convenience init(_ code: String, _ name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {

@StateRealmObject var country: Country2

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            
            Button("Change country", action: {
                let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0..<realm.objects(Country2.self).count)
                country = realm.objects(Country2.self)[randomIndex]. // Render OK
            })
            
            Text(country.name).padding()
            
            Button("Update name", action: {
                try! realm.write() {
                    country.thaw()!.name = country.name + "_ADD"   // No render
                }
            })
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    .background(Color.lightGrey)
    .onAppear() {
        try! realm.write() {
            realm.deleteAll()
            realm.add(Country2("AO","Angola"))
            realm.add(Country2("AR","Argentina"))
            realm.add(Country2("AT","Austria"))
            realm.add(Country2("AU","Australia"))
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear; *when the object changes* would the same as *when a property of the object changes* - changing a property of an object, changes the object. Can you clarify and update your question?

Comment: Just dit it, hope clearer.

Comment: That's better. The `StateRealmObject` is not documented very well, but it is in the API [StateRealmObject](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/StateRealmObject.html#/s:10RealmSwift05StateA6ObjectV12wrappedValueACyxGx_tcAA20ProjectionObservableRzrlufc). The usage shown is this `Text(model.title) // Updates the view any time title changes` so perhaps how the `.name` property is being updated is the cause? Can you try an [explicit write](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/write/#perform-an-explicit-write)

Comment: As far as I understood, I make an explicit write, which is OK as the country is correctly updated in the database. The problem is just the refresh of the view after the update.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking one thing and wrote something different. I suggest doing an [implicit write](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/write/#perform-a-quick-write) (e.g. a quick write)to see if the behavior is any different. Also, because SwiftUI property wrappers use frozen objects, before writing an object, the realm it belongs to must be thawed. Can you try thawing the realm first? `let realm = country.realm!.thaw()` and then use that realm to write

Comment: Same behavior unfortunately, anyway thanks...

Comment: Interesting. I copy and pasted your code and an implicit write updates the view. e.g. button click updates the name property and that updated name is shown in the view. I wonder what the difference is.

Comment: I really think you should be using [ObservedRealmObject](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/react-to-changes/#observe-an-object) here as that will fire the event you want and update the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not familiar with Realm using SwiftUI. You simply just copy you UIKit experience of the Realm and look something up on Realm for SwiftUI.

Read this first and refactor you code.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui-tutorial/

Or for the short version

https://zhaoxin.pro/16285779845842.html

Briefly speaking, you should use

```swift
@ObservedResults(Country2.self) var countries
```

instead of

```swift
@StateRealmObject var country: Country2
```

Comment: As far as I understood these are two different things, ObservedResults is for a full list of objects, and that works well, but in my case for only one object. StateRealmObject is part of the Realm library.

Comment: @Eric You didn't understand. Or perhaps, I didn't understand. In my option, StateRealmObject can not be used like you does. As one realm object has two states, one is created, which is unmanaged. After it is inserted to Realm, it becomes managed. StateRealmObject's state is not changed from unmanaged to managed, so it won't publish its changes as you expect. But ObservedResults will.

Comment: @OwenZhao I don't think that's what's being asked; the OP is not asking about an unmanaged object then becoming managed. They are asking; when an existing managed object's properties change, they want an event to fire notifying the app of those changes. Specifically - they only want to be notified about a *single object* (e.g. the view is updated to reflect that change), not multiple objects in a Results. The solution as I mentioned in a comment above is ObservedRealmObject

Comment: @Jay If I change from StateObject to ObservedRealmObject, it's not possible to update it anymore unfortunately ("'self' is immutable").

Comment: @Eric Of course you can! That's the point of the `ObservedRealmObject`. When it's updated the view refreshes. I suggest going back to the documentation as that process is covered **When you use the ObservedRealmObject or ObservedResults property wrappers, you can implicitly open a write transaction. Use the $ operator to create a two-way binding to the state object. Then, when you make changes to the bound object or collection, you initiate an implicit write.** Docs are here [Write Data](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/write/#write-data---swiftui)